# Template over a Hash Table value (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, hashtable, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm creating a hash table. Ideally the key should be of type int, and the value could be of any type (int, char, double, string, etc.) Here's my entry and table classes:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename P>
class HashEntry {
private:
      int key;
      P value;

public:
      HashEntry(int key, P value) {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
      }

      int getKey() {
            return key;
      }

      P getValue() {
            return value;
      }
};

const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;

template<typename P>
class HashMap {
private:
      HashEntry<P>**table;

public:
      HashMap() {
            table = new HashEntry<P>*[TABLE_SIZE];

            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  table[i] = NULL;
      }

      P get(int key) {
            int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);

            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                  hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

            if (table[hash] == NULL)
                  return -1;
            else
                  return table[hash]->getValue();
      }

      void put(int key, P value) {
            int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);

            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)    
                  hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

            if (table[hash] != NULL)    
                  delete table[hash];

            table[hash] = new HashEntry<P>(key, value);
      }     

      ~HashMap() {
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  if (table[i] != NULL)
                        delete table[i];

            delete[] table;
      }
};

int main()
{
    HashMap<char>* h1 = new HashMap<char>();
    h1->put(5, 15);
    cout << h1->get(5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is, when I try adding a template such as template typename P , I want to replace every instance of `int` for the variable `value` with `P` in both classes. Additionally, how would I be able to allocate this in main? There are no compile time errors with the above code, but when retrieving the value I get nothing.

Comment: May I recommend a search for c++ template programming

Comment: First off, use the initializer list to initialize member variables in the constructors. Second, if this is not for educational purposes use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Third use a `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. Fourth, if your compiler supports C++11 use smart pointers instead of raw pointers and `new/delete`. Do all these, and then we can talk of how to generalize your structures.

Comment: @40two Educational purposes. Another thing I wanted to ask: ideally, the hash table above accesses the value in O(1) time since the key is provided. However with std::map, it seems as if the only way to search is through an iterator (correct me if I'm wrong). Wouldn't that be O(n) time, thus defeating the purpose of a hash table?

Comment: @DarkKunai99 In `std::map` search/insertion/erasure is guaranteed for all cases `O(log(n))`. In `std::unordered_map` search is amortized time `O(1)`.

Comment: Can you clarify what is going wrong when you try to make this templated? It sounds like you're on the right track with changing the type of "value" to the template typename "P"

Comment: @iwolf Surprisingly enough, there aren't any compile time errors. But whenever I try retrieving the value it doesn't retrieve anything at all. I'll upload what I have now in just a second.

Comment: @DarkKunai99 Your example seems to work fine in VC2012 at least

Comment: I'm seeing the same result as DarkKunai99. What compiler are you working with for this?

Comment: having an empty line after EVERY line of code is not optimal as you effectively reduce to half the amount of code you can see in one screen / code block and you double the amount of scrolling you have to do to see the whole code. It is true that not having any empty lines is maybe even worst. You have to find a balance and insert empty lines in such a way that increase readability and emphasize semantics.

Comment: @bolov. My original code is properly indented, the above is a result of copying and pasting it over to the site.

Comment: don’t worry, everybody had problems in the beginning with formatting code here.

Comment: the problem is that you can't see character 15, try casting to int before printing or use 'a'.

Comment: @programmerjake Thanks Jake. I tried doing all sorts of casting including `int answer = (int) table[hash]->getValue();`, but the 15 is still hidden as you described. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DarkKunai99 use `cout << (int)h1->get(5) << endl;`